# How to generate LLVM IR code to call C++ STL function?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, intermediate-language

I want to generate LLVM-IR that contains a call to a C++ STL function. e.g. `std::sort()`.
I think I need to go through following steps to achieve the task.

1. Link `std::sort()` into the IR
2. Get a reference to function `std::sort()`
3. Create a call to `std::sort()` using `IRBuilder.CreateCall(~)`.

I'm not sure how to achieve the first step above.

Comment: Do you need `sort<T>` for a specific T? Or you want to sort on a type that you only know at runtime?

Comment: `std::sort` is a template, not a function.

Comment: @sbabbi Yes, I only need `sort<T>` for a specific `T`. I know which `T` to use at compile-time .

Comment: I can't really write a full answer right now. You are on the right track.
For step 1, i would simply compile a C++ source file with an instantiation of sort<YourType>. Then you get a pointer to such function and you cast it to intptr_t. 
For step 2, you create a constant value within LLVM using the intptr_t from the previous step, then you use a Bitcast to convert it to the correct function pointer type. Now you can use your function anywhere you want within LLVM.